# Debugging in the Windows Phone 7 Emulator browser?

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to test my [homemade JavaScript framework](http://github.com/tylermwashburn/Ally) in as many browsers as I can find. Today I realized that on my Windows computer, I could install the Windows Phone 7 developer tools and test in the emulator.

I did this, and sadly it does not work, but I have no idea how to tell what's going wrong. I don't have any idea how to try and fix it because in a framework, there are 1000 things that could go wrong, and all I have is to guess.

Does anyone know how to debug in the emulator browser, or am I just stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty tricky to debug JS in the emulator browser. You could use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) for monitoring network traffic. However, at the moment, the IE in WP7 is primarily based on Internet Explorer 7 (with some features ported from IE8). If you framework works with IE7, it should pretty much work on WP7 (although there are some changes in the WP7 browser).
The Mango update will bring this to IE 9. They are using the same IE 9 code base as the one on the PC.

Comment: Oh. So the browser has not been updated to IE9 yet? I don't aim to support anything earlier then IE8, because IE7 is just a train wreck when it comes to JavaScript. (and everything else) Not that IE8 is really much better..

Comment: @tylermwashburn - Not yet. The Mango toolkit will be released this month, but the actual Mango update is scheduled for later this year and that will include IE9.

Comment: But if it works in IE9, it should work in the Mango update then?

Comment: @tylermwashburn - It should do because the code base is exactly the same as it is on the PC. You'll be able to download the Mango toolkit within a couple of weeks, so you can test it on the emulator.

Answer (score 4):

In order to debug my Javascript, from my Javascript I call:

```
window.external.notify("Some debug message");
```

I subscribe to the WebBrowser ScriptNotify event in my XAML, then in my C#:

```
private static void ScriptNotified(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Script notified: " + e.Value);
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but there is no `window` namespace support in the WP7 browser.

Comment: There is at least to the extent of calling window.external.notify :-) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.scriptnotify(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 4):

This is perfect... 
I added the Script notifier to my MainPage.xaml.cs file with in the

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
```

Section and it works like a charme.

I then found this snipit:

```
  // provide our own console if it does not exist, huge dev aid!
  if(typeof window.console == "undefined")
  {
  window.console = {log:function(str){window.external.Notify(str);}};
  }

      window.onerror=function(e, url, lineNumber)
      {
          console.log("ERROR! : " +url + "(" + lineNumber + ") : " + JSON.stringify(e));
      };

  console.log("Installed console ! ");
```

here: http://sim4all.com/blogging/?p=266.. PLEASE note that i have modified the onerror to include line nr and file referance.

this implements a Console.log object and a onerror Message.. It ie really helpfull..

This whole operation is of caurse only needed befor the Cordova layer is loaded.. Then Cordova takes better care of this.

Hope it helps..
Kim