# Debug javascript on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, visual-studio-debugging

I am converting a PhoneGap App that runs gerat on iPhone and Android, to Windows Phone.
I have setup a development environment with Visual Studio 2010 but have huge problem debugging and even getting errors from the application.

I can insert log messages and some of them comes, but it does not help me if theer is a Javascript ERROR.. Can any of you help me..

Thanks in advance
Kim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, After some research have I found some snipits here and there to add console.log and onerror messages to the project.
Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13943345/809934

I hope it can help you 
Regards
Kim